# Merge content of Pandas dataframe's rows

Tags: python, pandas

Having dataframe as following:

```
1   Jacke Chan  China       1
2   Jason       Great       2
3   Statham     Britain     2
4   Rock        United      3
5   Dwayne      States      3
6   Johnson     California  3
7   Jack Ma     China       4
```

I need to get following:

```
1   Jackie Chan            China
2   Jason Statham          Great Britain
3   Rock Dwayne Johnson    United States California
4   Jack Ma                China
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df = df.groupby(by=[3], as_index=False).agg(' '.join).drop(columns=[3])
print(df)

                     1                         2
0           Jacke Chan                     China
1        Jason Statham             Great Britain
2  Rock Dwayne Johnson  United States California
3              Jack Ma                     China
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name ': {0: 'Jacke Chan',
  1: 'Jason',
  2: 'Statham',
  3: 'Rock',
  4: 'Dwayne',
  5: 'Johnson',
  6: 'Jack Ma'},
 'country': {0: 'China',
  1: 'Great',
  2: 'Britain',
  3: 'United',
  4: 'States',
  5: 'California',
  6: 'China'},
 'no': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 4}})


df.groupby("no").agg(" ".join).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

This also will work

```
df_new=df.groupby(3, sort=False)[1].apply(' '.join)
fd_new=df.groupby(3, sort=False)[2].apply(' '.join)
```